# TypeScript Mixins

Tags: typescript, mixins, typescript2.2

TypeScript 2.2 added [mixins](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html). However, when I try to run the sample code, it [shows an error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Point%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(public%20x%3A%20number%2C%20public%20y%3A%20number)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Person%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(public%20name%3A%20string)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Constructor%3CT%3E%20%3D%20new(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20T%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20Tagged%3CT%20extends%20Constructor%3C%7B%7D%3E%3E(Base%3A%20T)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20class%20extends%20Base%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20_tag%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20constructor(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super(...args)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._tag%20%3D%20%22%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20TaggedPoint%20%3D%20Tagged(Point)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20point%20%3D%20new%20TaggedPoint(10%2C%2020)%3B%0D%0Apoint._tag%20%3D%20%22hello%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Customer%20extends%20Tagged(Person)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20accountBalance%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20customer%20%3D%20new%20Customer(%22Joe%22)%3B%0D%0Acustomer._tag%20%3D%20%22test%22%3B%0D%0Acustomer.accountBalance%20%3D%200%3B), saying that `Base` is not a constructor function type.

```
class Point {
    constructor(public x: number, public y: number) {}
}

class Person {
    constructor(public name: string) {}
}

type Constructor<T> = new(...args: any[]) => T;

function Tagged<T extends Constructor<{}>>(Base: T) {
    return class extends Base { //ERROR HERE
        _tag: string;
        constructor(...args: any[]) {
            super(...args);
            this._tag = "";
        }
    }
}

const TaggedPoint = Tagged(Point);

let point = new TaggedPoint(10, 20);
point._tag = "hello";

class Customer extends Tagged(Person) {
    accountBalance: number;
}

let customer = new Customer("Joe");
customer._tag = "test";
customer.accountBalance = 0;
```

Is there something that needs to be changed in the declaration of `Constructor` to remove this error?

(Related, if the TS team reads this, the [handbook on mixins](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html) now appears to be out of date.)

Comment: Open up the browser console of the playground and look at the log statements. It's using an old version: `ts.version: 2.1.4-insiders.20161201`. Does the sample work for you with actually version 2.2? By the way, I've been using the new mixins extensively [here](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-simple-ast/blob/fb2c17724c1984be38ea386698318fba3abb886a/src/compiler/base/AsyncableNode.ts). I like it quite a lot.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I've been saying for years the playground needed a version toggle...

Comment: @MgSam so was the version the only problem? In which case, should you delete this question?